# How do I write a macro to change a list of numbers so that it increases on each sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a spreadsheet that has a list of numbers in column 2. I need to print 50 sheets at a time, with the numbers increasing on each sheet. I.e. sheet 1 starts with 2834 and ends in 2848; the next page starts at 2849 and end in 2863 and so on and so on. How do I write the macro and where do I put the macro? I'm at a loss.

I have never written a macro or used one but I'm sure this would be the solution, other than printing each page individually and changing the numbers each time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good starting point

```
Public Sub LotOfNumbers()
    lastSheet = 50
    numbersPerPage = 10
    selectedColumn = 2
    firstValue = 3000
    Dim wkb As New Workbook
    Dim wks As New Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    totalwks = Application.Sheets.Count
    i = 1
    actualValue = firstValue
    While i <= lastSheet
        If i <= totalwks Then
            Set wks = wkb.Sheets(i)
        Else
            wkb.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        For j = 1 To numbersPerPage
            Cells(j, selectedColumn) = actualValue
            actualValue = actualValue + 1
        Next j

        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Open VBA /Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

On the left side double click on The worksheet, on the right side paste the code.

Adjust the variables `lastsheet`, `numbersPerPage`, `selectedColumn` and `firstValue` to your liking.